# Reason for Segment fault in case of big array size

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have to make a rv32 simulator. In order to do that, I'm currently working on 'memory' class that will help me to keep track of memory.

Since the version, I'm working on is 32 bit, I need to on a data structure to represent the memory storage. Conceptually, memory is just an array of bytes, indexed using byte addresses, so I'm using an array to do it.

```
class memory {

 private:

  // TODO: Add private members here
  int * storage= new int [100000000];

 public:

  // Constructor
  memory(bool verbose);

  // Read a word of data from a word-aligned address.
  uint32_t read_word (uint32_t address);

  // Write a word of data to a word-aligned address.
  void write_word (uint32_t address, uint32_t data, uint32_t mask);

  // Load a hex image file and provide the start address for execution from the file in start_address.
  bool load_file(string file_name, uint32_t &start_address);

};
```

When I use the 'storage' array, it gives me a segment fault in the return statement if the address is like 80000000.

```
uint32_t memory::read_word (uint32_t address) {
  //rounding up multiple
  if((address %4 )!=0){
    int remainder =(address)%4;
    address=address-remainder;
  }
  return (storage[address]); 

}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] that replicates the problem to show us. I also recommend you use a debugger to catch the crash and take a look at both the original and calculated values of `address`.

Comment: In a class dealing with such huge amounts of memory, I would warmly recommend 1. to delete copy constructor and copy assignment (to prevent strange effects) 2. to write a destructor which frees the `new`ed memory. (Leaks with a size of round about 100000000 * 4 bytes can become really annoying...) ;-)

Comment: Usually memory is represented as array of bytes, not array of ints.

Comment: Please have a look std::array. I think it already does what you want. No need to invent the wheel twice.